# Passing parameters in truffle tests

Tags: michelson, taquito, truffle

I have this parameter for a function:

```
type modify_list is 
| Add of list(address)
| Remove of list(address)

type modify_list_michelson is michelson_or_right_comb(modify_list)
```

When I try to supply the parameter in my truffle tests like this:

```
{ add: [account1, account2], remove: [] }
```

I get this error:

```
Received 1 arguments while expecting one of the following signatures ([["add","list"],["remove","list"]])
```

Can anyone tell me how to supply the arguments correctly? I've tried simplifying the parameter with addresses instead of a list and tried pretty much every data structure I could think of in the JS test, but no success yet.

Comment: Do you have a deployed contract for that? I'd like to run some tests against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for the parameter is the following: `"remove", [account1, account2]` (2 different parameters, no object).
I built a simple contract to emulate your case, deployed it and wrote [a little script to test it](https://repl.it/@claudebarde/TestingUnionParameters#index.ts). After calling the entrypoint of your choice, you must provide 2 parameters: 1- the field you want to set the union value with 2- its parameters (if any).
Let me know if you have other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is that you pass the 2 parameters (add and remove), but you should only pass the chosen one.
I suggest you try : `{ add: [account1, account2] }`

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately I got the same error as well